# Integration testing Azure function app that connect to Service Bus queue

Tags: azure, queue, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-function-app

I have developed a function app that is triggered by a Http request, and peeks a respective queue (connects to it by a connection string) on the Service Bus for messages with a specific parameter value, and delete them.

In addition to regular testing when developing, it would be great to create integration tests and run them in a CI/CD process, but I don't know how to mock the queue that the function app connects too (creating a test queue that resides on the Service bus only to be used for test-purposes is not an option). Does anyone have any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options would be to provision a temporary Azure Service Bus namespace in the beginning prior to executing an integration test suite and tearing it down at the end. The namespace would be a standard tier namespace. Provisioning and tearing down could be done with either ARM template, PowerShell, or Azure CLI.

An additional benefit of this approach is security. A namespace per test suite run will ensure that PR from external contributors can be safely executed, in case your repository is public.